# Search keyboard Appium Java not function

Tags: java, selenium, appium-android

try to find a solution for this topic and none of the answers all the websites won't help me,

Search keyboard Appium Java not function

[image: Android Keyboard to be clicked via Appium in Java-client 6.1.0]

example not helping codes:

```
((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
```

same with:

```
driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
```

or:

```
((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKeyCode(66)
```

or:

```
((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKeyCode(84)
```

I'm using this appium version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

the option do it via coordinates not workaround for me since this tests done with a real mobiles and any mobile with a different screen size resolution

Sharing the exception and stack trace

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'Haims-MacBook', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:8ea:4c20:85c7:1988%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {appActivity: net.XXX.XXX.ui.acti..., appPackage: net.XXX.XXX.qa, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appActivity: net.XXX.XXX.ui.acti..., appPackage: net.XXX.XXX.qa, deviceName: Galaxy A20, noReset: false, platformName: android, platformVersion: 9}, deviceManufacturer: samsung, deviceModel: SM-A205FN, deviceName: R58M50DVABW, deviceScreenSize: 720x1560, deviceUDID: R58M50DVABW, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, noReset: false, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 9, takesScreenshot: true, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: ad88e2fa-102c-4e19-b8fa-ac48054838ff
```

Comment: indeed - 
post updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", "true");                                     
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", "true");
```

set this before trying

```
((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER)
```

Comment: My question exactly was about "Search" - "Search keyboard Appium Java not function", how can I click on the search key?

Comment: BTW, this option is also not working with a real device:
((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_SEARCH);

perhaps your suggest supposed to work only with Emulator?
but i need to test only in a real device.

anybody help! :-(

Comment: another thing may be forgot mention:
the real device is Android OS9
(Samsung Galaxy A20)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to press search button.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: performEditorAction", ImmutableMap.of("action", "search"));
```

If this doesn't work try replacing **search** with below commands

1. go
2. send
3. next
4. done

Also, if this doesn't work try giving 1 or 2 sec delay before the execution of this command.
For more information you can refer
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/